# How to get the top 10 value in BIRT

Tags: java, charts, birt

I have a trouble that I need to get the top 10 busiest stations, right now, I have these columns (number of buses, datetime, station name). Now, I can dynamically change the time range based on user's selection. But, the BIRT just show all the stations' name in one chart. How can I get the top 10 stations' name? I tried to add filter in my chart, but after I added it, it only showed one station name. Can anyone help me solve my problem? (In my chart, the X-axis is the station name, and Y-axis is the number of buses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because stations data are aggregated on-the-fly in the chart view, whereas the top 10 filter you added is filtering on details rows before aggregation. As far as i know we can't specify that a chart filter should be applied at a group level such as we can do it with a table element.

Therefore you should aggregate data before rendering the chart. There are a couple of ways to do this:

- Aggregate data in your dataset (SQL group by, ...)
- Aggregate in a hidden birt table element with groups, and base the chart on this table. Notice in this case the top 10 filter has to be defined in the table element
- Aggregate using a datacube, and base the chart on this datacube or a crosstab

If you cant't make it work as expected, for this kind of issue you should post a  .rptdesign based on "Classic models" database sample.